# SSL conf for Wazuh integration

Tags: wazuh

how can I specify ca-cert or disable SSL verification when setup Slack integration in Wazuh?
I can`t see any directive for this in docs (https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/reference/ossec-conf/integration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will need answer too. You can find out where python stores its certs bundle with

> ```
> import certifi
> certifi.where()
> ```

and append your cert there